# Percona Server - binlog not automatically purge with mysqladmin flush-logs

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, percona-server, binlog

I have a little problem and I need your help please. Here is the story : I have Percona Server in version 8.0.13 with one slave and the old binlogs on master are not deleted automatically when flush-logs appending.
Variables are set as :

```
# mysql -e"select @@expire_logs_days, @@binlog_expire_logs_seconds"
+--------------------+------------------------------+
| @@expire_logs_days | @@binlog_expire_logs_seconds |
+--------------------+------------------------------+
|                  0 |                        86400 |
+--------------------+------------------------------+
```

I have logrotate which execute `mysqladmin flush-logs` every night and binlogs are correctly rotated but old ones are not removed. When I execute this command manually the behaviour is the same.

In MySQL CLI the command `PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE datetime` works fine.

The slave replication is up to date or a little bit late but not more than a couple hour. So it can't be explain why old binlogs are still present on disks (some are 7 days old by example)

I also execute `lsof` to check if MySQL retain descriptor on old binlogs but **no**. I have no more idea to explain the problem.

Do you have any ideas to explain and fix this please ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Please note Paragraphs 2,3 in the MySQL Documentation for [binlog_expire_logs_seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds):

> The default binary log expiration period is 2592000 seconds, which equals 30 days (30*24*60*60 seconds). The default applies if neither binlog_expire_logs_seconds nor the deprecated system variable expire_logs_days has a value set at startup. If a non-zero value for one of the variables binlog_expire_logs_seconds or expire_logs_days is set at startup, this value is used as the binary log expiration period. If a non-zero value for both of those variables is set at startup, the value for binlog_expire_logs_seconds is used as the binary log expiration period, and the value for expire_logs_days is ignored with a warning message.
>
> To disable automatic purging of the binary log, specify a value of 0 explicitly for binlog_expire_logs_seconds, and do not specify a value for expire_logs_days. For compatibility with earlier releases, automatic purging is also disabled if you specify a value of 0 explicitly for expire_logs_days and do not specify a value for binlog_expire_logs_seconds. In that case, the default for binlog_expire_logs_seconds is not applied.

Please review your my.cnf

If you have this line in the `my.cnf`

```
expire_logs_days = 0
```

change it to

```
expire_logs_days = 1
```

Then go execute

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days = 1;
mysql> FLUSH BINARY LOGS;
```

This will cause a new thread to be opened with the new setting.

It's OK to have

```
expire_logs_days = 1
binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 86400
```

because the documentation says when both are set, [binlog_expire_logs_seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds) will take precedence and a simple warning is posted for [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days).

As a last resort, please restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

If you still have a problem after doing this, then I would suspect a bug.

Comment: Thanks RolandoMySQLDBA for your reply !
When I try to change `expire_logs_days` value i get an error :
`ERROR 3683 (HY000) at line 1: The option expire_logs_days and binlog_expire_logs_seconds cannot be used together. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds to set the expire time (expire_logs_days is deprecated)`.  

And I don't understand why I need to define `expire_logs_days` becaus the documentation says :  
`If a non-zero value for one of the variables binlog_expire_logs_seconds or expire_logs_days is set at startup, this value is used as the binary log expiration period.`